# Cocoa move directories

Tags: cocoa, nsfilemanager

How do I move directories in cocoa?

Whenever I use NSFileManager I get an error.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager moveItemAtPath:[srcpath retain] toPath:[dstpath retain] error:&error];
```

I end up getting the error:

> nameOfDir1 couldn't be moved to nameOfDir2

Comment: Why are you retaining those paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I had to enter the directory name that I'm copying after the directory that I'm copying to.

Comment: Yes. NSFileManager won't imply the source directory's name if you leave out the name from the destination path; it sees that you passed a destination directory that already exists and rejects that.